# xul - no or wrong toolbarbutton image

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I spent a whole day on something so trivial as this one, still can't
make this work. A huge weird image appears instead of my icon. If I take out the toolbarbutton-1 class no image will appear at all. Here are all the stuff that matters: (This is going to be an awfully long post...)

My XUL contains only a toolbarbutton on the toolbarpalette:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://ytweaks/skin/style.css" type="text/
css"?>
<overlay id="yTweaks" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/
gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script src="main.js" />
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="ytweaks-main-button" class="toolbarbutton-1
chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
            type="menu"
            label="yTweaks"
            tooltiptext="yTweaks"
            state="enabled">
        </toolbarbutton>
    </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

And the CSS is the same as the one in the MDN tutorial:

```
#ytweaks-main-button {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://ytweaks/skin/icon.large.png");
}

toolbar[iconsize="small"] #ytweaks-main-button {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://ytweaks/skin/icon.small.png");
}
```

The manifest file looks like this:

```
content ytweaks chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://ytweaks/content/ui.xul

skin ytweaks classic/1.0 skin/classic/ytweaks/
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://ytweaks/skin/style.css
```

And the folder structure:

```
chrome
|-- content
|   |-- ui.xul
|   |-- main.js
|-- skin
    |-- classic
        |-- ytweaks
            |-- icon.large.png
            |-- icon.small.png
            |-- style.css
```

And finally, the result looks like this:
[image]

Totally not the same icon I made. This is my icon that should appear (the
large one): [image]

---

Also, how can I debug these stuff? For example, how can I browse the
chrome registry. If I type a chrome URI in firefox nothing happens.
Except for the browser's main XUL file which loads another full
browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be due to invalid path here:

```
skin ytweaks classic/1.0 skin/classic/ytweaks/
```

..which should be:

```
skin ytweaks classic/1.0 chrome/skin/classic/ytweaks/
```

Re: debugging. I'd test 3 things:

- Use the simplest rules that you know must match, then check the styles on the element in question with the DOM inspector to see if your rules match. If they don't your stylesheet didn't get applied for some reason.
- Look really close at the line that applies the stylesheet (in your case it's the `style` line in your chrome.manifest). I don't know how you can debug typos here.
- Check that the chrome:// URL to the stylesheet is working when you open it via the Location bar. It's supposed to display the text of your css file.

  - If you get `No chrome package registered for chrome://aaa/skin/aaa.css` message in the Error Console, your `skin` declaration in chrome.manifest didn't get processed or the 'provider' name (`aaa` in my example above) doesn't match the 'provider' name specified after "skin"
  - If you get an in-content error page saying `File not found. Firefox can't find the file at chrome://aaa/skin/bbb.css` (as in your case), it means the path part of the `skin` declaration is incorrect. It should be relative to the chrome.manifest (and iirc ending with a /)

Comment: the Error Console does show some XUL errors. But only if I use "reload all Chrome" of DOMi. Using restart gets wiped on startup I guess. Whoa you made my day (night), now my motivation, to achieve stuff, is back.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the information you gave above, if this is your path `ytweaks/skin/icon.small.png` but your folder structure is

```
 |-- ytweaks
     |-- icon.large.png
     |-- icon.small.png
     |-- style.css
```

Then it looks to me like you are either missing a `skin` subfolder in `ytweaks` or you should not have that in your image path.

Comment: There might truly be a problem, but that's not this simple. For  handling multiple skins or something, you got to use the manifest file. This line: "skin ytweaks classic/1.0 skin/classic/ytweaks/" overrides the path, but I'm not sure how, and this is how on other add-ons I've seen they did. But doesn't work for me. The add-on I compared mine to was flash block, opening the xpi file as zip, then the jar also as zip you can find similar structure. The main difference is that while that one works mine doesn't.